# Google Wallet not installing

Tags: google-play-store, installation, realme, google-wallet

I am running Android 12 on a Realme 8 5G phone.

When trying to install Google Wallet from the Google play store, I get the following screenshots:

[image: screenshot 1]
[image: screenshot 2]
[image: screenshot 3]
[image: screenshot 4]

In the end, after the third screen below I land on the second screen below again, and get stuck in a loop.

The application won't finish installing.

Can someone please explain to me what is going wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the "Google Play (clone)" app?